# Compare smoothed signal to the input signal

Tags: numpy, signal-processing, scipy

I smooth a series of data points using the algorithm described here: http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/SignalSmooth .

How could I compare the smoothed signal with the input signal afterward? I'm hoping I could get a scalar describing how "close" the output is from the input. Is there any standard way to do this? Some term I could look for?

I have no idea what to even look for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [normalized root mean squared deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square_deviation#Normalized_root_mean_squared_deviation). That gives me a number between 0 and 1. The bigger the number, the further away the two data series are. 0 means perfect match between the signal and the smoothed signal.

Answer (score 3):

Discrete correlation is a way to detect a known waveform in a noisy background. Just find the correlation between two signals. Discrete correlation is simply a vector dot product:

```
for n in range(N):
   y[n] = sum( [x1[i]*x2[i+n] for i in range(N)] )
```

in pure Python, or:

```
y = xcorr(x1,x2);
```

in Matlab, or:

```
y = correlate(x1,x2)
```

in Python+Scipy.

Correlation is a very sensitive measure of similarity of two signals. It is maximized when the two signals are similar in frequency content and are in phase with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you smoothed the signal to remove noise, the most natural figure of merit would be the SNR.

So something like:

```
mean((smoothed[n] - original[n])^2) / mean( (smoothed[n])^2 )
```

The above assume the average of the signal is ~0.

Comment: I smooth the signal in order to approximate it. I have a series of data points (measurements), but 1) I don't have a value for every point I'm interested it and 2) the measurements can have small errors. I plot a nice curve that represents the approximated signal alongside with a scatter plot of the measurements. The scatter gives me an idea of how far off the approximation is, but I'd like to have a number that I can easily compare. Average of the signal is not 0.